# Probability: Two six-sided dice

Tags: probability

Two six-sided dice each have faces representing numbers from 2-7. When these dice are both rolled at the same time, what is the probability of the sum of the two (n) satisfying the equation -2n+19>6?

Comment: Give it a shot and we'll help you along.  Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I solved for n. n<6.5 so that gives us these possibilities for the dice rolls: a roll of 2 in combo with 3 or 4 (for the second die), 3 with 2 or 3, or 4 with 2. Those are the only combinations which give us a sum less than 6.5. I *think* the probability of rolling these combos is 1/6, but I'm not sure if there is another step involved in solving for all the different rolls or not...? The answer choices are: 1:6, 1:4, 1:2, 3:4 or 5:6

Comment: I realized I also forgot the combo of 2 rolled with another 2!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by solving the inequality.

$$-2n + 19 > 6$$
$$-2n > -13$$
$$2n < 13$$
$$n < 6.5$$

So now we know the sum of the numbers on the two dice needs to be 6 or less. Also, since the numbers on the dice are 2-7, the minimum sum can be $2 + 2 = 4$. So, we need the sum to be 4, 5, or 6.

Here are the different ways in which we can have these sums.

4 → (2, 2)

5 → (2, 3) or (3, 2)

6 → (3, 3), (2, 4), or (4, 2)

So, in all 6 ways. These satisfy the given inequality.

Altogether, there are 36 different outcomes possible $(6 \times 6)$ when we roll the two dice.

So the required probability would be -

$$\frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6}$$